# How to run multiple tiny Ruby (Rack) apps on one server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

I want to run several (more than 2) tiny Rack-based apps on my VPS, which already has one large Rails app running.

The Rails app uses the traditional pair of Unicorn & nginx, and it requires most of the RAM that I have on my VPS.

I've tried adding similar Unicorn configurations for each app and it led me to conclude the RAM is insufficient.

So my question is: is it possible to set up one small memory-saving server which allows me to run several Sinatra apps at once?

UPDATE: in case it matters, I don't care much about the performance. These apps are not intended to do any serious jobs.

UPDATE 2: an approach based on sockets shared with Nginx is preferred over the one with ports.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not run the apps on the same unicorns as the main app?  Just hack the routes into the rackup file.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this too. As well as about setting up a middlewares chain. The problem - this will result in logical inconsistency - all my apps are not related to each other in any way.

Comment: What is interesting here is to find an approach for having 'multiple tiny Rack apps on one server'. I want to know, if it is possible in general.

Comment: "Logical inconsistency"?  You just said that one server per app didn't work out, so what other choice do you have?

Comment: I don't understand either. Why do you think using unicorn to run apps requires the apps to be related to each other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did my own exploration of this question and I think I found a solution which will allow me having one web-server running all my tiny apps at once.

It is based on **RackStack** not-yet-a-gem created by Remi Taylor (**@remi** on Github) https://github.com/remi/rack-stack.

RackStack is inspired by Rack::Builder, which as well seems being good for accomplishing a task like this - RackStack just goes in the same direction further, abstracting "stack" functionality in a way I found very nice and handy.

Here is a demonstration of RackStack which consists of two sample apps (Sinatra and Rack):  https://github.com/stanislaw/skeletons/tree/master/rack_stack. To mimic stack app behavior on a real server I modified my /etc/hosts file to have localhost2 host pointing to 127.0.0.1.

I fire up Thin server and then run requests on localhost or localhost2: the requests to 'localhost' are served by FirstApp,  to 'localhost2' by SecondApp.

I can't now foresee any problems that can appear, when I will test my apps on a real server, but now this approach seems to be exactly what I was looking for: I imagine, that on a real server Nginx will pass requests to all the hosts associated with my rack apps to a socket listened by Thin server. So, RackStack will meet only those requests which are addressed to the apps I have in my stack.

Any suggestions, improvements of this scheme or alternatives are still appreciated!